# Consultar número de viviendas según el catastro usando Google Maps

Tags: google-maps

Lo que quiero conseguir es marcar uno o varios polígonos o formas en Google Maps y que se realice una consulta que me devuelva en número de viviendas según el catastro.

Esta es una imagen de lo que deseo conseguir:

[image]

¿que debo hacer después de añadir los controles de diseño al mapa?
¿Como guardo los polígonos o formas realizados?
¿Como debo codificar la información para enviarsela al castro y éste me devuelva el dato deseado?

Comment: Hola David, bienvenido. Deberías añadir el codigo que tengas y que has intentado. Mostrarnos los errores que te han salido o explicar por qué lo que has probado no dio los resultados esperados. Un saludo

Comment: Tienes una tabla con las coordenadas de las viviendas en alguna parte? Quieres guardar también los poĺígonos en esa parte?

Comment: Se incluyen tres preguntas, cada una de las cuales me parece que deberían publicarse como preguntas independientes. Por favor revisa [ask].

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con Rubén. A parte de que tenemos que intuir que deseas hacer una petición al catastro de España. Actualmente sin certificado digital la información q más tendrías al alcance es hacer una petición GetFeatureInfo al servidor WMS o utilizar el servicio WFS.